# Why would you not want to create a backwards relation on a foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models

I recently came across [this paragraph](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in the Django docs on the `related_name` attribute of the `ForeignKey` field:

> If you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set `related_name` to `'+'` or end it with `'+'`. For example, this will ensure that the `User` model won’t have a backwards relation to this model:
>
> ```
> user = models.ForeignKey(
>     User,
>     on_delete=models.CASCADE,
>     related_name='+',
> )
> ```

Under what circumstances would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recall being puzzled by that as well. However, in the years since I've found myself occasionally doing it. If you know you'll never need the related manager, there are a few minor advantages to telling Django not to create it.

1. It serves as documentation that you're not using that relation. That could be helpful to future readers. That's the main reason I do it, to say to myself or others in the future: "This design does not envision using this relation, so pause to think about it if you think you need it."
2. It avoids cluttering the namespace of the target instance. Some people care about this.
3. It avoids the overhead of creating the unneeded manager, which should theoretically improve performance. In the absence of any benchmarks I would expect any such improvement to be very minor.

To put it differently, normal good coding practice is to not add code that you don't need. This option allows you to keep Django from adding code that you don't need.

Now, I still don't know why you'd want to "end it with +" instead of just using "+"!